# What does 'Nummer' refer to in "Auf Nummer sicher gehen"?

Tags: etymology, meaning-in-context, expression

What does 'Nummer' refer to in "Auf Nummer sicher gehen"? I understand that this phrase means something like the english expression "to play it on the safe side" meaning, when faced with a choice, to select the less risky option. However, what does 'Auf Nummer' or just 'Nummer' refer to in the german expression?

Answer (score 6):

Die Redewendung kommt von „auf Nummer sicher setzen“ und meint Straftäter in eine (nummerierte) Gefängniszelle einsperren ([Referenz](https://www.geo.de/geolino/redewendungen/8797-rtkl-redewendung-auf-nummer-sicher-gehen)). Du setzt den Straftäter also auf „Nummer sicher“, was hier ein Synonym für die Gefängniszelle ist.

Im [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Nummer) findet sich dazu ebenfalls eine Referenz (Danke *user unknown*):

> auf Nummer sicher sein/sitzen (umgangssprachlich veraltet: im Gefängnis sein; bezieht sich darauf, dass Gefängniszellen nummeriert sind und die Inhaftierten darin »sicher« verwahrt sind)

Comment: Referenz hin oder her, die Erklärung ist alles andere als plausibel. Es soll ausdrücken, dass man vor dem Verbrecher sicher ist, wenn dieser auf Nummer sicher sitzt? Auf Nummer sicher gehen heißt aber nicht, dass die anderen vor mir sicher sind. Das wirkt mehr als fischig auf mich.

Comment: Lt. Duden (weit unten) https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Nummer sind "Auf Nummer sicher sein/sitzen" und "auf Nummer sicher gehen" zwei unterschiedliche Redewendungen. Da sie gegensätzliches bedeuten haben sie womöglich unterschiedlichen Ursprung.

Comment: @userunknown Vermutung: ich gehe vielleicht auf Nummer sicher, indem ich dich erst einmal einsperre, egal ob das nun berechtigt ist, oder nicht. Aber du hast Recht, mit dem gehen das klingt blöd. Allerdings sagt der Duden nicht wirklich was dazu, ist also ein schlechter Gegenbeweis.

Comment: Du würdest dann sagen "Du gehst auf Nummer sicher", nicht "Ich geh auf Nummer sicher". Und der Duden führt es als andere Redewedung auf, hält das offenbar nicht für synonym. Ich bin aber nicht vertraut mit Dudens Auflistung von Redewendungen, für mich legt nur das Layout nahe, dass das was anderes ist.

Comment: @userunknown: Nein, man sagt _Ich gehe auf Nummer sicher._ Damit ist aber nicht gemeint, dass man irgendwo hingeht oder sich selbst in die Gefängniszelle sperrt, sondern eher, dass man die _Nummer sicher_ (die _sicherere Option_) verwendet.

Comment: @clemens: Laut Duden heißt aber "auf Nummer sicher sein/sitzen" "ins Gefängnis gehen". Es besteht kein inhaltlicher Zusammenhang zu "auf Nummer sicher gehen", alleine das war aber gefragt.

Comment: @userunknown: Aber die Herkunft von _... gehen_ von _... sitzen_ geht doch aus dem Geolino-Artikel hervor, oder lässt du den nicht gelten? Die Bedeutung ist doch die gleiche. Wenn ich auf Nummer sicher gehe, dann prüfe ich alles alles noch mal, um bloß keinen Fehler zu machen. _Auf Nummer sicher setzen_ heißt nach dem Duden ja auch, dass ich den jemanden ins Gefängnis _stecke_, um sicher zu sein, dass er keinen Schaden anrichtet.

Comment: @clemens, Nein, der Geolinoartikel eiert erst rum: "kommt eigentlich von" - was soll das 'eigentlich'? Kommt es daher oder nicht? "Wer allerdings heute auf Nummer sicher gehen möchte, der will natürlich nicht unbedingt direkt ins Kittchen wandern" wieder Geeier. Er will nicht ins Kitchen, wa? Wieso unbedingt, wieso direkt? Mit Tatütata und rotem Teppich nicht unbedingt? "Dann kann er genauso sicher sein, wie ein Inhaftierter in der Gefängniszelle." Ohne große Empathie mit Inhaftierten - der Inhaftierte sitzt nicht zu seiner eigenen Sicherheit in der Zelle, aber das unterstellt der Text…

Comment: … zynischerweise. Ein Fall für die Müllverbrennungsanlage. Es ist nun für die Interpretation der Aussagen "auf Nummer sicher gehen", "auf Nummer sicher sein/sitzen" von entscheidendem Belang, wer da das Subjekt ist, und wer das Objekt. Man geht nicht in den Knast um auf Nummer sicher zu gehen. Das ist nicht austauschbar mit "auf Nummer sicher sitzen" aber das wäre notwendig, wenn man das eine aus dem anderen ableiten wollte. Dass die Allgemeinheit dann sicher ist passt auch nicht, weil man nicht nach Sicherheitsbedarf Leute wegsperren kann. Die Geolinos oder die, von denen Geolino …

Comment: …abgekupfert haben, haben nicht verstanden, dass das zwei unterschiedliche Redewendungen sind, und beim Zusammenbasteln der Erklärung die weithin unbekannte Redewendung, vom auf Nummer sicher sitzen, für eine Variante gehalten und sind dann nonchalant über die selbst empfundene Unstimmigkeit hinweggetrottelt, nicht ohne eine freudsche Spur zu legen "sichert sich nur gegen alle möglichen Unstimmigkeiten ab". Nix wurde abgesichert, es wurde verbockt und eine vielköpfige Medusa in die Welt gesetzt. Die Hitlertagebücher (Führer Hitler, FH als Initialien) hatten mehr Qualität.